# How do I work in one branch, but commit my work to another?

Tags: git

Imagine the following scenario. I work in branch `foo` and have some uncommited edits. I want to commit my edits in branch `wip/foo` without committing or loosing work in branch `foo`. Is it possible, and how do I do it?

### Progress

I ended up writing the following script:

```
#! /bin/bash

# usage: wipscript.sh repo file branch
#
# For example,
# wipscript.sh ~/repo file.sh development

repo=$1
file=$2
branch=$3

cd $repo
hv=`git rev-parse HEAD`

branch_present=`git branch | grep wip/$branch`
# echo $branch_present
# echo "------"

git add $file
git commit -a -m $file

if [[ $branch_present == *"wip/$branch"* ]]
then
    # echo "in then"
    git checkout wip/$branch;
else
    # echo "doing else"
    git checkout -b wip/$branch;
fi

git checkout $branch -- $file
git commit -am $file

git checkout $branch
git reset --soft $hv

# echo "Finished."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to stash them.

Uncommitted changes don't exist in any branch. Simply change branches and commit:

```
git checkout wip/foo
git commit
```

If `wip/foo` doesn't exist yet, use `git checkout -b wip/foo instead`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the stash mechanism:

```
git stash
git checkout wip/foo
git stash pop
```

Comment: Thank you for putting me back on track. If I add: git commit FILE ; git checkout foo ; git checkout wip/foo -- FILE seems to do what I want.

Comment: I ran into problems with stash conflicts